# Iterating over an array and doing answer validation using AWS Lambda function

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, aws-lambda, matching

I'm a new dev looking for guidance. I'm writing out an AWS Lambda function for the purpose of array validation.
Say I have the first array of

```
{"food":"ribs", "snacks":"doritos", "drinks":"pepsi"}
```

and the second array of

```
{
  "answer": {
    "food": [
      "ribs",
      "pasta",
      "ramen"
    ],
    "snacks": [
      "doritos",
      "cheetos",
      "popcorn"
    ],
    "drinks": [
      "orange juice",
      "apple juice"
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I do validation on the first array using the correct answers on the second array?

The validation should return {"true","true","false"}

I'm getting confused on how to start/what method to approach

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to lop for the answer key and check with `hasOwnProperty()` function as follow:

```js
function validateArray(firstArray, secondArray) {
    const validationResults = [];

    // iterate through the keys in the first array
    for (const key in firstArray) {
        // check if the key is present in the second array
        if (secondArray.answer.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const validationResult = secondArray.answer[key].includes(firstArray[key]);
            validationResults.push(validationResult);
        } else {
            validationResults.push(false);
        }
    }

    return validationResults;
}

// as you provided
const firstArray = {"food": "ribs", "snacks": "doritos", "drinks": "pepsi"};
const secondArray = {
    "answer": {
        "food": ["ribs", "pasta", "ramen"],
        "snacks": ["doritos", "cheetos", "popcorn"],
        "drinks": ["orange juice", "apple juice"]
    }
};

const result = validateArray(firstArray, secondArray);
console.log(result); // as You needed the output is [true, true, false]
```

Comment: Hi Ermi. Thank you so much. I would like to ask what is key? Is it a constant we are defining?

Comment: In JavaScript objects, a "key" refers to the property name of an object. An object is a collection of key-value pairs, where each key is a unique identifier for a specific value. If you have any question, I welcome. And if you find the question helpful, please accept it.

Comment: Hi Ermi, thank you for your response. What is an example of a key in this situation? It seems the key changes, which is why I'm a bit unsure?

Comment: The keys in the first array are "food", "snacks", and "drinks". These keys are used to identify the corresponding values, which are "ribs", "doritos", and "pepsi" respectively, like this it is the same for the second object but you are defining an array with a key.